# Month and year to display inbetween dates by creating a new table

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

I'm using MS Access 2010 and am writing a program to display the lease amount to be paid over a period of 36 months. Once I have entered the contract into a table I use the following expression:

```
Charge: IIf(Date()>[1StartDate] And (Date())<=[2StartDate],[1Sched],
        IIf(Date()>[2StartDate] And (Date())<=[3StartDate],[2Sched],
        IIf(Date()>[3StartDate] And (Date())<=[4StartDate],[3Sched],
        IIf(Date()>[4StartDate] And (Date())<=[5StartDate],[4Sched],
        IIf(Date()>[5StartDate] And (Date())<=[EndDate],[5Sched],"0")))))
```

This shows the correct Rental amount to be invoiced but I would like to display the entire 36 months schedule so that when I run batch invoicing one specific month at a time will be ticket off as having been processed.  How may I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. To get a faster answers Kindly format your question and the code part within with proper formatting tags provided above the Rich Text field

Comment: Have you considered writing a function that returns the charge? You could then call it in a query or after update event.